cannot install yay -S --noconfirm bambustudio-git after yay -Syu to local/gcc 14.2.1+r134+gab884fffe3fc-1
I did a system upgrade on manjaro using yay -Syu. It appears it upgraded gcc to some experimental version.

I tried reinstalling gcc13 but it didn't fix the problem:

export LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS/-fuse-ld=mold/-fuse-ld=ld}" before trying to install.
export CC=gcc-13 CXX=g++-13 before trying to install.


yay -S base-devel installs the experimental gcc 14.2.1+r134+gab884fffe3fc-1 again if i try to uninstall it.

I queried 3 different llms and got no useful answers.


Here are the logs:
yay -S --noconfirm bambustudio-git
AUR Explicit (1): bambustudio-git-01.06.00.65.15.g693af0c9-1
:: PKGBUILD up to date, skipping download: bambustudio-git
  1 bambustudio-git                          (Build Files Exist)
==> Packages to cleanBuild?
==> [N]one [A]ll [Ab]ort [I]nstalled [No]tInstalled or (1 2 3, 1-3, ^4)
==> 
  1 bambustudio-git                          (Build Files Exist)
==> Diffs to show?
==> [N]one [A]ll [Ab]ort [I]nstalled [No]tInstalled or (1 2 3, 1-3, ^4)
==> 
==> Making package: bambustudio-git 01.07.01.62.4.g5ef759ce-1 (Wed 06 Nov 2024 04:07:17 PM)
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Updating BambuStudio git repo...
  -> Found BambuStudio.cpp.patch
  -> Found CMakeLists.txt.patch
  -> Found wxWidgets.cmake.patch
  -> Found bambu-studio.sh
==> WARNING: Skipping verification of source file PGP signatures.
==> Validating source files with sha512sums...
    BambuStudio ... Skipped
    BambuStudio.cpp.patch ... Passed
    CMakeLists.txt.patch ... Passed
    wxWidgets.cmake.patch ... Passed
    bambu-studio.sh ... Passed
:: (1/1) Parsing SRCINFO: bambustudio-git
==> Making package: bambustudio-git 01.07.01.62.4.g5ef759ce-1 (Wed 06 Nov 2024 04:07:19 PM)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Updating BambuStudio git repo...
  -> Found BambuStudio.cpp.patch
  -> Found CMakeLists.txt.patch
  -> Found wxWidgets.cmake.patch
  -> Found bambu-studio.sh
==> Validating source files with sha512sums...
    BambuStudio ... Skipped
    BambuStudio.cpp.patch ... Passed
    CMakeLists.txt.patch ... Passed
    wxWidgets.cmake.patch ... Passed
    bambu-studio.sh ... Passed
==> Removing existing $srcdir/ directory...
==> Extracting sources...
  -> Creating working copy of BambuStudio git repo...
Cloning into 'BambuStudio'...
done.
Updating files: 100% (6964/6964), done.
==> Starting prepare()...
patching file BambuStudio/CMakeLists.txt
Hunk #1 succeeded at 745 (offset 54 lines).
==> Starting pkgver()...
==> Updated version: bambustudio-git 01.10.00.81.10.g733531b-1
==> Sources are ready.
==> Making package: bambustudio-git 01.10.00.81.10.g733531b-1 (Wed 06 Nov 2024 04:07:23 PM)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> WARNING: Using existing $srcdir/ tree
==> Starting pkgver()...
==> Removing existing $pkgdir/ directory...
==> Starting build()...
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:23 (project):
  cmake_minimum_required() should be called prior to this top-level project()
  call.  Please see the cmake-commands(7) manual for usage documentation of
  both commands.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-13
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-13 - broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/gcc-13"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: '/tmp/makepkg/bambustudio-git/src/BambuStudio/deps/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-c94XFe'
    
    Run Build Command(s): /usr/bin/cmake -E env VERBOSE=1 /usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_b88fe/fast
    /usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_b88fe.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_b88fe.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/makepkg/bambustudio-git/src/BambuStudio/deps/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-c94XFe'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_b88fe.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    /usr/bin/gcc-13   -march=native -O2 -pipe -flto=auto  -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_b88fe.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /tmp/makepkg/bambustudio-git/src/BambuStudio/deps/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-c94XFe/testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_b88fe
    /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_b88fe.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/bin/gcc-13 -march=native -O2 -pipe -flto=auto  ... -fuse-ld=mold -flto=auto  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_b88fe.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_b88fe
    mold: fatal: cannot open ...: No such file or directory
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_b88fe.dir/build.make:99: cmTC_b88fe] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/makepkg/bambustudio-git/src/BambuStudio/deps/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-c94XFe'
    make: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_b88fe/fast] Error 2
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:23 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
 -> error making: bambustudio-git-exit status 4
 -> Failed to install the following packages. Manual intervention is required:
bambustudio-git - exit status 4

I assume the issue is the mold command cannot understand "..." (Variadic directory listing?)

Does Manjaro install multiple GCC versions help?

@eyoung100 I think the problem is related to mold. Its failing to interpret the "..." but I can't figure out which version of which binary is failing

Try building this without using mold as a linker.  If the build succeeds without mold you need to file an issue on the mold github.  I pulled up Bambu Studio also, but it's listed as Public Beta 2.0 with 2.7k Open Issues.  You may want to file an issue there asking to support mold  We need to do this to rule out whether its a problem with the new linker or with the source code.
